VS Code always gives includePath errors for custom headers. How do I fix it?
In my attempt to make the program, I always run into includePath errors in my VS Code. I can only import standard libraries like stdio.h, stdlib.h and such header files only. In case I try to import a custom header file, say gtk-3.0, I run into includePath errors. Even for files that were installed with msys2 like openssl. I need your help to learn more and fix this issue. So that despite using any header file (in-built or external) without running into includePath error squiggles in VS Code forever.
Here is what I have done:
I am trying to build a simple project with gtk-3.0 which validates phone numbers. My setup is Windows 11 with Visual Studio Code. I have installed C development environment using MSYS2 from here: https://www.msys2.org. After installing MSYS2, I ran the following commands in the MSYS utility -
pacman -Syu
pacman -Su
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo mingw-w64-x86_64-pango mingw-w64-x86_64-gdk-pixbuf2

After this was done, I added the following to both user and system environment variables:
D:\ProgramFiles\msys64
D:\ProgramFiles\msys64\ucrt64\bin
D:\ProgramFiles\msys64\ucrt64\include
D:\ProgramFiles\msys64\mingw64\bin
D:\ProgramFiles\msys64\mingw64\include

In my VS Code, I have configured c_cpp_properties.json like this:
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/**",
        "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0",
        "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0",
        "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/ucrt64/include/**",
        "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/pango"
      ],
      "defines": [],
      "compilerPath": "D:\\ProgramFiles\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "browse": {
        "path": [
          "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/**",
          "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0",
          "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0",
          "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/ucrt64/include/**",
          "D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/pango"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}

Everytime I try importing external headers, like #include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h> the line is squiggled and I get this error on hover:
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (E:\Projects\C\phval.c).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "pango/pango.h" (dependency of "C:\Users\adars\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.20.5-win32-x64\bin\gtk-3.0\gtk\gtk.h")C/C++(1696)

And another error:
E:\Projects\C>cd "e:\Projects\C\" && gcc phval.c -o phval && "e:\Projects\C\"phval
phval.c:1:29: fatal error: gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.

This happens despite explicitly adding gtk-3.0 to includePath in the cpp configuration. Please help me fix this. I don't understand why it is unable to find pango.h as I have explicity added D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/pango and it contains the said file. Thus, this being the reason, I would like to find a way so I can just include a path after which I don't have to specifically mention includePaths to pango.h or other million dependencies.
This might be a novice question, but I would really appreciate solutions.

Build-settings are made in tasks.json, if you use the Microsoft C and C++ plugin instead of the default code-runner plugin which you seem to do. Please read the documentation.

@Someprogrammerdude I did a few changes and I don't get the includePath errors anymore at least in this case (no, I didn't disable the errors). But now, all I get is E:\Projects\C>cd "e:\Projects\C\" && gcc phval.c -o phval && "e:\Projects\C\"phval phval.c:1:29: fatal error: gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory  #include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>                              ^ compilation terminated.
But I don't understand why this is happening because the files exist in the path. The fix I did was making Intellisense and Compiler to msys gcc.

IncludePath setting only affects Intellisense errors. It has no effect on the compiler. You must tell the compiler where to find the headers as well. Use command line argument -I <path> for each include folder. That should go into tasks.json file

Also, if you have an #include "pango/pango.h" and the include path is D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/pango, the total result will be D:/ProgramFiles/msys64/mingw64/include/pango/pango/pango.h, which is probably one pango too many.

In C language,
standard library headers are included using <> like this:
#include <stdio.h>
But, for other library headers like gtk, double-quotes are used:
#include "gtk.h"
I am a layman.
I am just sharing what I understood. Hope it works!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
